# ggplot2: Missing x labels after expanding limits for x axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I imagine that my question is trivial, but I can't figure it out. I have an yearly data which I want to display using ggplot2 barplot. As my bar for the first year is too close to y axis, I want to expand limits of x axis. However, if applied, my X axis values disappear, even theme() specification does't produce results.. and I don't understand why? Could the reason be that I am using "years" as factors? But for bar representation  I need  to use discrete scale...

Thank you !

```
# reproductible exemple

year<-c(2003:2010)
manag<-rep(c("A", "B"), 4)
np<-rep(c(0,1), each = 4)
val<- c(10,20,50,10,14,80,19,25)

df<-data.frame(cbind(year, 
                     manag, np, val))

require(ggplot2)

a<-ggplot(data = df, aes(x = as.factor(year), y = val)) + 
  ggtitle("MISSING X VALUES!!!") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits= c(2002:2015)) 
  # theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size = 8, colour = "black", angle = 90)

b<-ggplot(data = df, aes(x = as.factor(year), y = val)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  ggtitle("NOT EXPANDED X LIMITS")

grid.arrange(a, b, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First your data.frame code needs cleaned. 
Remove the cbind  - cbind is turning everything into a factor

```
  df<-data.frame(cbind(year, 
                  manag, np, val))
```

so that it looks like

```
  df <- data.frame(year, manag, np, val))
```

Then the x-axis will be on a continuous scale e.g.

```
ggplot(df, aes(year, val))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+ 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2002:2010), 
                     labels = factor(2002:2010), 
                     limits = c(2002,2011))
```

You can change the labels to something like

```
labels = c("", factor(2003:2010))
```

if you don't want the 2002 in there

Comment: you are the R wizard @BWilliams ! thank you ! ;) the proposition with 'labels = c("", factor(2003:2010)' doesn't work for me, but modification in 'breaks = c(2003:2010)' works great to not to display the limiting values.

Comment: I had a similar issue with `geom_rect`, converting discrete x axis factor levels to `as.numeric` in the plot so I could fine-tune placements, but then calling `scale_x_discrete` to make it appear discrete again. The x axis values disappeared and I could not get them back until I set the `limits` argument in `scale_x_discrete` to a character vector of the original axis labels; setting `labels` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Whole code with vertical adjustment of x ticks and x labels for barplot with factors, based on @BWilliams answer:

```
year<-c(2003:2010)
manag<-rep(c("A", "B"), 4)
np<-rep(c(0,1), each = 4)
val<- c(10,20,50,10,14,80,19,25)

df<-data.frame(year, manag, np, val)

ggplot(df, aes(year, val))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+ 
  facet_grid(np ~ manag) +

  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2003:2010), 
                     #labels = c("", factor(2003:2010)),
                     labels = factor(2003:2010),
                     limits = c(2002,2011)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size = 8, colour = "black", angle = 90, hjust = 0, 
                                 vjust = 0.5)) # center the x tick with label name
```

[image]